# Run powershell script from anywhere in the PC

Tags: command-line, powershell, script

Powershell script, on my Desktop screen, that executes commands on files in a certain folder. When I run the script on the desktop, it works, but when I move the script to another location, it doesn't run and it doesn't generate anything!. How to make a powershell script work from anywhere on my PC?

follow script:

```
Write-Host "Enter the LUFS value you intend to Normalize Files" -ForegroundColor Yellow
[decimal] $vLUFps= Read-Host -Prompt "LUFS value"

$logMatches = Select-String -Path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\*.log" -Pattern '(?<I>^ +I:) +(?<LUFS>.+)' -List | Select-Object -Property FileName -ExpandProperty Matches
    $results = foreach ($log in $logMatches) {
        $LUFS = $log.Groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "LUFS" }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Nome = $log.Filename
            LUFS = [decimal]$($LUFS.Value -replace " .*")
        }
    }
    $vLUFps+= -0.9
    $results | Where-Object { $_.LUFS -lt $vLUFps } | Out-File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\A LISTA DE MÚSICAS APTAS para Normalização.txt"
```

Note:
When run via powershell command line, the output filename is created correctly in the folder, however when run via ps1 script,
the file name is generated with codes in place of the special characters.

Correct name of output file generated in powershell command line:
`A LISTA DE MÚSICAS APTAS para Normalização.txt`

Wrong name of output file (generated with codes) in place of special characters, when I run the script outside the powershell command line:
`A LISTA DE MÃšSICAS APTAS para NormalizaÃ§Ã£o.txt`

Comment: Is the `.ps1` file marked as being UTF-8 with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? You can use Notepad++ to add the BOM.

Comment: @harrymc ok, that solved the name problem,. Regarding the beginning of my post, do you know how I can make the script run from anywhere on my PC?. thanks

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: @harrymc when it is on the desktop screen and when I move it into another folder, I run it in the same way, using the right mouse button on top of the script and selecting the option Run with Powershell. It happens that the script that is inside another folder, does not execute the commands and does not generate the files, the script only works when it is on the desktop screen.

Comment: Try `set-strictmode -off` ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-7.2)).